# C# MAUI ListView and Data Binding, doesn't work and gives no errors either

Tags: c#, maui

I'm trying to learn how to build mobile apps using C# MAUI. I'm going through many tutorials, videos, searching online, even tried to use AI to help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.
App is compiling without any errors, starts but when I navigate to MainCategoriesPage nothing happens, no error but then I can't change to different page. I spent loads of time trying to figure out myself, but I got to the point I'm giving up and need someone to explain me what I'm doing wrong.

I have file Views/MainCategoriesPage.xaml with content of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SugarRays.Views.MainCategoriesPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:SugarRays.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MainCategoriesPageViewModel"
             Title="MainCategoriesPage">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MainCategories}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:MainCategory}">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Column="0"
                           Source="{Binding Image}"
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="60"
                           WidthRequest="60" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                           FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Views/MainCategoriesPage.xaml.cs

```
using SugarRays.ViewModels;

namespace SugarRays.Views;

public partial class MainCategoriesPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainCategoriesPage(MainCategoriesPageViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
```

Then I have ViewModels/MainCategoriesPageViewModel.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace SugarRays.ViewModels;

public class MainCategory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}


public partial class MainCategoriesPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<MainCategory> mainCategories;

    public MainCategoriesPageViewModel()
    {
        MainCategories = new ObservableCollection<MainCategory>
        {
            new MainCategory { Name = "Gloves", Image = "gloves.png" },
            new MainCategory { Name = "Punch Bags", Image = "punch_bags.png" },
            new MainCategory { Name = "Footwear", Image = "footwear.png" },
            new MainCategory { Name = "Club Shop", Image = "club_shop.png" },
            new MainCategory { Name = "Protective", Image = "protective.png" },
            new MainCategory { Name = "Apparel", Image = "apparel.png" },
            new MainCategory { Name = "Equipment", Image = "equipment.png" },
            new MainCategory { Name = "Sale", Image = "sale.png" }
        };
    }
    
}
```

I tried many different ways, I created static hard coded page which looks and works just fine. When I try to do it with data binding, simply doesn't work...

Comment: Try replacing ViewCell with a simple TextCell.  Get that to work first, then worry about the more complex layout.  Also, have you debugged your VM to verify that the data is being created as expected?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any errors, so I didn't think about putting any break points for debugging, thanks to your reply I found out MainCategoriesView is not being created. I've added MainCategoriesPageViewModel to services and it works like expected!

```
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<CategoriesStatic>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainCategoriesPage>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainCategoriesPageViewModel>();
```

Comment: Hi  @Artur, could you please mark your answer as marked so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this is not an answer, I observed two enhancements you may like to consider.

The first point, within your `MainCategory` view model the `Image` property can be derived from `Name` so we can rewrite it as:

```cs
public partial class MainCategory : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Image))]
    private string _name;

    public string Image
        => $"{Name.ToLower().Replace(" ", "_")}.png";
}
```

The second point is the initializer for `MainCategories` can now be optimized, because (1) the `Image` property is taken care of so we can now omit it from the initializer, (2) there is a noticeable pattern in how you're populating the list so start with a string constant/string array and use that to derive your list:

```cs
MainCategories = new ObservableCollection<MainCategory>(
    "Gloves,Punch Bags,Footwear,Club Shop,Protective,Apparel,Equipment,Sale"
    .Split(",").Select(n => new MainCategory { Name = n }));
```

Comment: My model is much bigger and complex, for testing and learning purposes I’ve created this simple model so I could easily debug and understand than with huge model I’m getting from outside API.